# No viable overloaded on XML parsing program

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing

I have the following code which compares an XML file, then uses a map to define types of content against the names of nodes, and uses an if command to try and take actions depending on what tag is found.

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagMap {
        {"description", "content"}, {"url", "web_address"}
    };

    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) { 
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* id = node.child_value("id");
    mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
        mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }

     for (auto& eb: mapb) {
         for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
         kv.first = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
             if (kv.first == "id") {
             // Do work on id 
             }
             if (kv.first == "description") {
             // Do work on description 
             }
             if (kv.first == "url") {
             // Do work on URL data (I.e validate it)
             }
             if (kv.first == "location") {
             // Do work on location data
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The issue I get is when I try and compile this program I get this error:

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I include -o main src/main.cpp include/pugi/pugixml.cpp 
src/main.cpp:46:19: error: no viable overloaded '='
         kv.first = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
```

This is an example input:

```
<data>
<entry>
<id>1</id>
<content>Test</content>
<web_address>test.com</web_address>
</entry>
</data>
```

Comment: You are trying to change the map's key elements. Why do you want to change those? Can you not just assign `eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str())` to its own variable and make your `if()` tests using that?

Comment: @Galik I can do, yes, but what I'm confused about how to relate it back to the mapping. For example, if it reads a ```content``` tag I want to put it in the category for ```is a description``` because my map defines the content tag as a description.

Comment: @Galik That would mean ```<content>Test</content>``` would fall in the ```if x == "description") {``` so I can do work on the test "Test"

Comment: I don't see that. You map the tag name to its normalized value and then check that mapped name. I think you just need to use a separate variable to temporarily store the mapped name rather than the input name.

Comment: @Galik Is this code closer to the mark ```if (kv.first == "id") {
    std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());}```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but I am thinking something more like: `std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str()); if(var == "id") {} else if(var == "url") {} etc...` but maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be off base here but based on your description I think you might be looking for something like this.

I suspect your tag-map is backwards but I was unable to get this working on your example data so there may be other things missing too.

Hopefully what I have done might be of some use.

```
int main()
{

    // I think maybe your map is backwards?
    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagMap {
//        {"description", "content"}, {"url", "web_address"}
        {"content", "description"}, {"web_address", "url"}
    };

    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) {
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("entry")) {
    std::string id = node.child_value("id");
    mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("data").children("entry")) {
    std::string idcs = node.child_value("id");

        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
        mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }

    // Use this to find mapped nodes
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator found;

     for (auto& eb: mapb) {

             // try to find the node in the map
             found = tagMap.find(eb.second.child_value());

             if(found == tagMap.end()) // - FAIL
                 continue; // unknown tag - ignore

             // test the corresponding (mapped) tag name

            if (found->second == "id") {
                 std::cout << "// Do work on id" << '\n';
             }
             if (found->second == "description") {
                 std::cout << "// Do work on description" << '\n';
             }
             if (found->second == "url") {
                 std::cout << "// Do work on URL data (I.e validate it)" << '\n';
             }
             if (found->second == "location") {
                 std::cout << "// Do work on location data" << '\n';
             }
//         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I would print out the contents of the tag within the if tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can't overwrite the key in an associative container such as `std::map`---it will always be returned to you as a `const` reference. Indeed, if you were allowed to overwrite the key then you could very easily violate the container's invariants. The usual solution is to delete the element and insert a new one with the updated key.

Comment: So it's this line which is the problem? ```kv.first = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());```. I need to check what type of information it is, using the map, i.e ```<content>Test</content>``` is a description. How do you recommend I get around this based on what you have said?

Comment: @Jimmy You are trying to overwrite the keys in the map `tagMap` and I'm telling you that this cannot be done. If you need to overwrite the values, that is fine, you can just assign to `kv.second`.